# Getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to take a screenshot in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, nullpointerexception, selenium-chromedriver

Getting null pointer exeption when trying to take a screenshot. line 42 is
File trg = new File (System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\Screenshots\homepage.png");

```
        public class Screenshot {
        
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException   {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                        "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\IT\\Bright Path Technology\\Selenium Folder\\Browsers\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
        
            
                WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
                driver.get("https://www.nopcommerce.com/en/demo");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                
                TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
        
                File src = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                
            File trg = new File (System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Screenshots\\homepage.png");
                
            FileUtils.copyFile(src,trg);
    
    }}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.io.File.<init>(File.java:276)
    at day24Scrol.Screenshot.main(Screenshot.java:42)
```

Comment: According to the stack trace, it happens in the constructor of `File` but this should only happen if the path itself is null. Are you sure you posted exactly the code you wrote and haven't e.g. made a typo?

Comment: Also you are providing a path which already contain homepage.png. Does homepage.png exist

Comment: What does System.getProperty("user.dir") returns.it should return your working directory. Sometimes you need to set it before getting it if it returns null.

Comment: The exception almost certainly was caused by different code than what you’ve posted.  There is only one call to `new File` in the code you’ve shown, and it is impossible for the argument to that constructor to be null.